Generate a random list based on a main list (consisting two columns)
I want to generate a random list  from a main list based on two columns as shown in this pictures. The generated list values can be repeated and duplicated. the names and designation values are linked with each other. it does not need to be in any special order.and for names e.g. Name1 the designation must be Designation1. as shown in the output.


Add a numerical column next to your input, starting from 1 and increasing by one. In a new column, generate random numbers from 1 to the maximum number from your input list. Use INDEX/MATCH to look up the names and designations.
To generate an integer from 1 to the required maximum:
=INT(RAND()*3)+1

To look up the required values from the random integer:
=INDEX($A$2:$A$4,MATCH(E2,C$2:$C$4))




Using table and a named formula:


Add a table for the main list - mainList
Define a name for the random row, randomRow
=RAND()*ROWS(mainList) + 1
Enter in adjacent cells, for example G2:H2

=INDEX(mainList,randomRow,1)
=VLOOKUP(G2,mainList,2,FALSE)


Drag down these two as needed


With named range and named formula:


Create a name for the range containing the main list - main_list

adding a table is a better option


Define a name for the random index, rand_idx
=TRUNC(RAND()*ROWS(main_list) + 1)

Then (as in Michal's method),

enter the index in one cell, F2 in the example, =rand_idx
select the adjacent two cells, G2:H2 in the example
enter =INDEX(main_list,F2,{1,2}) in G2 as an array formula by pressing Control + Shift + Enter



Select these three cells and drag down



While Excel allows to easily use of additional columns and rows which can be hidden to keep the layout, the solution which doesn't require an additional column (or row) can be helpful in some cases.

Formulas:
E2 and fill down =INDEX($B$2:$B$13,1+12*RAND())
F2 and fill down =VLOOKUP(E2,$B$1:$C$13,2,FALSE)

